# Graphing a relationship of a real world scenario

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Kate and William are getting married. They found a charming venue with a maximum capacity of $50$ people. The venue costs $1000$ dollars, and the caterer charges $50$ dollars for every person who attends the wedding (including the bride and groom).
Besides Kate and William, there are $10$ close family members who will definitely be attending, and they wondered how many additional guests to invite. They decided to graph the relationship between the number of additional guests and the total price per person.

Which axis should represent the price per person?

Potentially, mathematical variables can have any value, but the variables under discussion here are bounded by the real-world context they model.

What is the range of valid values for the price per person?
If necessary, round your answer to the nearest cent.

Steps I took:

I realized that the expression to describe the relationship would be $50x+1000$. However, they gave me more information by saying that the bride, groom and $10$ close family members will be attending for sure. This allowed me to alter the expression to $50x+1600$.

I also know that the price per person is an independent variable and should be represented by the horizontal axis. However, the second part is not as clear to me. I don't understand what they mean when they say "valid values for the price per person".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the contrary, the price per person is the dependent variable. That is, the price charged per person depends on the number of people attending. To see this for yourself, consider the case in which only Kate, William, and the ten guests are attending. Then, the total price is $\$1,000 + 12*\$50 = \$1,600$, for a price of $\$1,600/12 = \$133.33$ per person. However, if they max the venue, the total cost will be $\$1,000 + 50*\$50 = \$3,500$, for a price of $\$3,500/50 = \$70$ per person.

Clearly, the price per person depends on the number of people attending the wedding.

This also answers the second question. We're interested in the range of plausible answers for the cost per person. The two extreme cases are only the guests who are known to arrive will arrive, or that the venue's capacity is maxed. For instance, the price per person can never be below seventy dollars, since we know fifty is the maximum number of people the venue can hold (note that any number of guests below fifty will result in a higher price per person).

Answer (score 1):

The price per person is not an independent variable. The price per person *depends* on the number of people attending, meaning that the number of people attending (or the number of additional guests) is the independent variable.

Also, your formula, $50x + 1600$, is the total price, not the price per person. To calculate the price per person, think about this:

> If $10$ people attend the ceremony and it costs $1000$ dollars, then what is the price per person? How did you calculate this price per person? How can you calculate the price per person in general?